# Get the current bounded object in a ListView's ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, listview

I want to be able to get the current bound object in the `ItemTemplate` of a `ListView` control.

Here's an example of what I want to do:

```
<asp:ListView ID="UserList" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        //How can I get the current bound object in here?
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can access it via the DataItem:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "myPropertyName")%>'
```

If you wanted a textbox for example:

```
<asp:Label ID="MyProp" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("myPropertyName") %>' />
```

If you just want the full object:

```
<%# (MyType)Container.DataItem %>
```

Comment: I want the instance of the object, not its property.

Comment: @Andreas - in that case just `<%# (MyType)Container.DataItem %>` and do whatever you want with it...if you just need an plain object, don't cast.

Comment: Nick, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Change your answer to include that in it and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Andreas - Fair enough, better for the next person that comes along looking as well, updated :)